# Need some help in java Bit operations?

Tags: java, bit-shift

I have a byte array as: 00SSSMMM

I want to retrieve SSS and MMM values as int values.

Can someone help me in implementing this in java ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use bitwise operators (&) and shifts (>>), see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
int x = ...
int m = x & 0b111;
int s = (x >> 3) & 0b111;
```

Comment: Thanks. 

This works if: x is read as int x = 0b111010;

Can we read x as x = 00111010?

Comment: @LearnTrix provided that is in binary. If it is decimal you need to use `% 1000` and `/ 1000`